# How do I get rid of the background-image showing up again at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to get rid of the background-image showing-up again, guess it has something to do with &:before, I hope you can help me.
Thx in advance.

http://codepen.io/ctrprt253/pen/qZVKKG

```
.bg-image{
  background: $color-primary;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  //text-shadow: 2px 0 5px black;

  &:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #333     url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6E1qWDwgvPE/UW1IxACizzI/AAAAAAAAAOc/5COs8aubq4c/s1600/the_art_of_conversation_by_rttmsdag-d32q8oc.jpg') no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    filter: blur(5px);
    opacity: .8;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :

```
background: #333     url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6E1qWDwgvPE/UW1IxACizzI/AAAAAAAAAOc/5COs8aubq4c/s1600/the_art_of_conversation_by_rttmsdag-d32q8oc.jpg') no-repeat top center;
```

By that :

```
background: #333;
```

And you can remove these lines :

```
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[See it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKoeXg)

Comment: Thx, but then it disappears in the header too, I just need to get rid of it when it appears at the bottom a second time.
Any ideas?

Comment: Then remove class `bg-image` in the bottom container :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGpExZ

Comment: you're welcome, put this subject as resolved if it's ok for you :)